# how do i put lookout search box onto the Home Tab in outlook 2010

Tags: plugins, microsoft-outlook-2010

i have lookout working with outlook 2010 but it shows up on the "add ins" tab.  Is there anyway i can get this to show up on the home tab.  I see i can customize the ribbon but i dont see any option to put addin specific buttons or controls onto different tabs

Comment: comments on deleted answers provided this link for intalling Lookout in Outlook 2010: http://www.belshe.com/2007/12/06/how-to-install-lookout-on-outlook-2007/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't either (not with LookOut, with another Outlook add-in).

Maybe it's not yet possible, don't forget Outlook 2010 (and all the Office 2010 suite) is still in Beta version, thus not complete. And modifying the Ribbon is a new feature: it was fixed in Office 2007, and there was no Ribbon on the main window of Outlook 2007.

I suppose Microsoft prefers to make sure all its own stuff works fine before helping managing other companies' features.

Answer (score 0):

The only option to get it in to the outlook main view (without losing focus from the home  tab) is by doing this:
1. Go to the Add In tab

2. Right click the ribbon and choose "Add Group To Quick Access Toolbar"
3. Right click the ribbon and choose "Show Quick Access Toolbar Above The Ribbon"

Now at the top you have you have the "custom toolbars" icon and clicking it opens up the lookout options.

Hope this does the work.

Good luck,
Asher